# Propagate view state change to another view in the same layout

Tags: android, state

I have layout with 2 views (v1, v2), there is drawable selector defined as background for v1. That selector defines drawable for pressed state. What I want is to press v2 and see v1 turning into pressed state as well. How to do that?

Comment: Try to add to layout: android:addStatesFromChildren="true" and for second view android:duplicateParentState="true". Hope it helps

Comment: Tried that, but android forbids to use both addStatesFromChildren in parent and duplicateParentState in child.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Maybe you can create custom view and manage this logic inside this custom view…  Maybe there is better solution, I don't know =(